# SecIdentity + Force Cast Violation: Force casts should be avoided. (force_cast)

Tags: swift, security

Please dont mark repetitive question.

HI all,

I am doing NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate in which I am using the following code. In which code is fine if I dont use swiftlint. But when I use swiftlint I am getting this error and unable to solve this. Tried a lot please help me . Posting the code below.

```
    var items: CFArray?
    //let PKCS12Data = DataSourceManager.sharedInstance.serverPolicyManager?.PKCS12Data
    securityError = SecPKCS12Import(certData, options, &items)

    if securityError == errSecSuccess {
        let certItems: CFArray = items as CFArray!
        let certItemsArray: Array = certItems as Array
        let dict: AnyObject? = certItemsArray.first
        if let certEntry: Dictionary = dict as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            // grab the identity
            let identityPointer = certEntry["identity"]
            let secIdentityRef = identityPointer as!  SecIdentity
            print("\(String(describing: identityPointer))  :::: \(secIdentityRef)")
            // grab the trust
            let trustPointer: AnyObject? = certEntry["trust"]
            let trustRef: SecTrust? = trustPointer as! SecTrust
            print("\(String(describing: trustPointer))  :::: \(trustRef)")
            // grab the cert
            let chainPointer: AnyObject? = certEntry["chain"]
            identityAndTrust = IdentityAndTrust(identityRef: secIdentityRef, trust: trustRef!, certArray:  chainPointer!)

        }

    }
```

I am getting forcecast violation in the below lines.

`let secIdentityRef = identityPointer as!  SecIdentity`

`let trustRef: SecTrust? = trustPointer as! SecTrust`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, what you're doing is a force downcast, meaning that you guarantee that yours `identityPointer` and `trustPointer` are objects of `SecIdentity` and `SecTrust` classes respectively. But what if they are not? You take them out of the dictionary as `AnyObject`, so generally they may not cast to the target classes. Swiftlint tells you, that force casting is a bad practise and wants you to avoid it.

However, it seems with CoreFoundation type you can't use a conditional cast `as?`, so force cast is your only choice. For this particular case you can disable Swiftlint rule in code adding a special comment.

```
let secIdentityRef = identityPointer as! SecIdentity // swiftlint:disable:this force_cast
```

To be on the safe side, you also may check the identity of the object by checking the Core Foundation "type id":

```
guard let identityPointer = certEntry["identity"],
    CFGetTypeID(identityPointer) == SecIdentityGetTypeID() else {
    // here you know that the cast will fail
}
let secIdentityRef = identityPointer as! SecIdentity // swiftlint:disable:this force_cast
```

Comment: I tried in that way with guard in that case "Conditional downcast to CoreFoundation type 'SecIdentity' will always succeed" error is appearing. I tried in many ways but my understanding is unable to type cast Corefoundation objects.

Comment: To be honest, didn't know these were CoreFoundation objects. Made some research and updated the answer!

Comment: could you please update answer if you know how to solve this

Comment: already updated the answer with the special comment you may add in your code to make Swiftlint ignore these downcasts

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.